# CSS transition to fade in image isn't working

Tags: css, css-transitions

Please can you help troubleshoot the transition in this CSS? My browser can see the code in the inspector but no transition is taking place.  I have tried operating the transition on different properties including width and position but nothing works.

```
    #header-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s linear 1s;
}
```

I know I'm probably being thick so apologies in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css transition opacity fade background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145621/css-transition-opacity-fade-background)

Comment: transition only works if you are changing a property, if you want to animate something without a property changing, then you probably want to use a keyframes animation instead

Comment: @Pete thank you so much!  I knew I was being an idiot.  Keyframes animation did what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `transition` to work.. the property value should change. only then it will trigger the transition. 
i.e) lets say `#header-image` initially has `opacity: 0; width: 50px;`. 
but when you hover it you want to increase the opacity and width `opacity: 1; width: 250px;`

so your css will look like..

```css
    #header-image {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        background: blue;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        animation: fadeIn 2s linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="header-image"></div>
```

Then your transition will work. So basically `transition` will work only when there is a change in the value. But in your case you are setting the `opacity:1` initially by default.

If you want to add this effect on page load then you have to use css animation or javascript. Below I have given an example snippet on how it can be achieved using css animation.

However if you are planning to use many animations then I recommend to use some popular libraries like [Animista](https://animista.net/), [Animate.css,](https://animate.style/) [wow.js](https://wowjs.uk/)

Comment: Thank you for explaining!  That makes sense. How can I make it transition automatically with the page load instead of requiring a user action?

Comment: If you want to do it on page load, you have 2 options.
1.) you can achieve it using javascript. or 2.) you can use css animation.

Comment: I'll update my above answer to include css animation.