# Why CSS open event of summary tag not perform?

Tags: html, css, html-tag-details

I am trying to make `<detail>` tag style more comfortable, and the opacity changage does not work, when I open the `<detail>` tag.

Here is my code:

```css
details:not([open]) > :not(summary){
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
}
details[open] > :not(summary){
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<details>
<summary>Details tag</summary>
<p>Now, it shows details</p>
</details>
```

I want it can change opacity gradually. I also want a CSS-only solution and the CSS could not use animate(`@keyframes`), because it is easier for me to maintain the website.

If someone can let the code work, it is the best solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css transition opacity fade background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145621/css-transition-opacity-fade-background)

Comment: The `-webkit-` prefix for `transition` is obsolete and should not be used. Use `transition-duration` - also, you aren't specifying the property-name that `transition` should be transitioning... also, `[open]` controls `display: none;` which cannot be transitioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When details tag is collapsed, all elements except summary are hidden.
You cannot animate from hidden state.

When details expanded, `open` attribute added.
Target open attribute.

```css
    details[open] {
        animation: fadeIn .35s ease-in-out;
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <details>
        <summary>Details tag</summary>
        <p>Now, it shows details</p>
    </details>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
details > :not(summary) {
  animation: fadeIn .35s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Details tag</summary>
  <p>Now, it shows details</p>
</details>
```

Comment: This only animates once: the first time the `<details>` is expanded - on subsequent expansions it doesn't animate.

Comment: That works, but I also want a CSS-only solution and the CSS could not use animate(@keyframes). Also, it seemed that it only perform once.